# Template Init-constructor error

Tags: c++, templates, constructor

Hey I'm having trouble figuring out how to get my template header to work. I have to get my init constructor to take in an array and reverse it. So for example if I have [1,2,3,4] it takes it in [4,3,2,1]

this is my template class:

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template<typename DATA_TYPE>
class Reverser
{
private:
    // Not sure to make this DATA_TYPE* or just DATA_TYPE
    DATA_TYPE Data;
public:
     // Init constructor
     Reverser(const DATA_TYPE& input, const int & size)
    {
        // This is where I'm getting my error saying it's a conversion error (int* = int), not sure
        // What to make Data then in the private section. 
        Data = new DATA_TYPE[size];
        for(int i=size-1; i>=0; i--)
            Data[(size-1)-i] = input[i];
    }

    DATA_TYPE GetReverse(){
        return Data;
    }

    ~Reverser(){
        delete[] Data;
    }
```

};

So yea if you could tell me what I'm doing wrong that'd be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because when you pass array to function it converts to pointer. You must use DATA_TYPE as pointer:

```
template<typename DATA_TYPE>
class Reverser
{
private:
    // Not sure to make this DATA_TYPE* or just DATA_TYPE
    DATA_TYPE* Data; //pointer
public:
     // Init constructor
     Reverser(const DATA_TYPE* input, const int & size) //pointer
    {
        // This is where I'm getting my error saying it's a conversion error (int* = int), not sure
        // What to make Data then in the private section. 
        Data = new DATA_TYPE[size];
        for(int i=size-1; i>=0; i--)
            Data[(size-1)-i] = input[i];
    }

    DATA_TYPE* GetReverse(){ //Returns Pointer
        return Data;
    }

    ~Reverser(){
        delete[] Data;
    }
};
```

Comment: Usage: int* arr = new int[4];
       Reverser<int> r(arr, 4);

Comment: Ok, yea I was initiating it wrongly, however when I'm trying to retrieve the data using GetReverse(), I assume it should be a int* result = new int[10]; result = reverseData.GetReverse(); however I get the conversion error int to int*

Comment: Update answer look at getReverse

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me like you are declaring an instance of this class with `int`, like

```
Reverser<int> myVar;
```

Then the `Data` member will be of type `int`. In the constructor you then try to allocate memory (with `new` returning a `int*`) and assign it to the `Data` member, but you can't assign a pointer to a non-pointer.

So as you write in your comment, it should be

```
DATA_TYPE* Data;
```